# I have a question about the [multiple] screensaver app(s) I have installed

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, 20.04, screensaver, xscreensaver

I have just upgraded to Xubuntu 20.04, but I believe this was the same way under 18.04 as well, I am just now getting around to look at the issue.

If I go to `Xubuntu menu -> Settings`, there are two "Screensaver" apps available. Looking at them in "Edit Applications", they are:

- xscreensaver-demo
- xfce4-screensaver-preferences

Clicking on each one brings up a slightly different control panel, with different options.

If I go to `Xubuntu menu -> Session and Startup -> Application Autostart`, there are two "Screensaver (Launch screensaver and locker program)" options available there, they are:

- xfce4-screensaver
- /usr/share/xscreensaver/xscreensaver-wrapper.sh -no-splash

My questions are:

1. What is going on here?
2. Are these redundant installs?
3. Can I remove one or more of the redundancies?

Comment: You've installed multiple screensaver apps. These two are different apps, with different configuration choices. Uninstall the one you're not using, if the twoness bothers you.

Answer (score 0):

xscreensaver and xfce4-screensaver are two different screen saver and locker apps. xfce4-screensaver is listed as recommended package for xubuntu-desktop since 19.10 and that is why it was installed in the upgrade. However, there are some issues with xfce4-screensaver in Xubuntu 20.04 (and maybe in 19.10, too). Can you tell there, if the following bugs affect you?
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-screensaver/+bug/1876602
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-power-manager/+bug/1877556

If you want to use less experimental software, you could uninstall xfce4-screensaver and use light-locker or xscreensaver, instead.